# Why is angular-debounce broken in v1.3.0?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

Check fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9sqtvcou/1/

Type something in the input and then wait 500ms. If you change the "external resources" to version 1.2.27 (latest v1.2 as from the date I posted this) it works, otherwise it doesn't.

This is the potential relevant code:

```
var debounceDuration = $parse($attrs.debounce)($scope);
var immediate = !!$parse($attrs.immediate)($scope);
var debouncedValue, pass;
var prevRender = ngModelController.$render.bind(ngModelController);
var commitSoon = debounce(function (viewValue) {
  pass = true;
  ngModelController.$setViewValue(viewValue);
  pass = false;
}, parseInt(debounceDuration, 10), immediate);
ngModelController.$render = function () {
  prevRender();
  commitSoon.cancel();
  //we must be first parser for this to work properly,
  //so we have priority 999 so that we unshift into parsers last
  debouncedValue = this.$viewValue;
};
ngModelController.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
  if (pass) {
    debouncedValue = value;
    return value;
  } else {
    commitSoon(ngModelController.$viewValue);
    return debouncedValue;
  }
});
```

I am not familiarized with angular, so I am wondering: what happened that broke angular-debounce in v1.3?

EDIT:
An answer with technical details would have priority over abstract ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/shahata/angular-debounce/issues/12

As angular-debounce creator and angular contributor, shahata said:

> debounce is supported natively in angular 1.3 using ng-model-options.

That is why angular-debounce is broken at angular v1.3.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to a [breaking change in 1.3.0](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/dbe381f29fc72490f8e3a5328d5c487b185fe652). Instead of the custom directive, try changing your view to:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="chapter.title" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/w89ow20f/

Comment: is it possible to do: ng-model-options="{ debounce: vm.delay }"